# can scrolling be smoother than single line in emacs/org-mode?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

Using the trackpad, the scrolling in emacs/spacemacs is notably less smooth than in modern browsers and other editors. I have to confess that this jerkiness irks me more than I would prefer but I have not found a way to improve that situation. It is especially distracting once non-text elements appear on screen (e.g. inline images) but the problem is bad enough with text-only.

Is this an emacs problem that everyone has learned to accept or is there a solution that everyone is using without even thinking of it?

Any help would be much appreciated, especially if it was assuming little background knowledge (I am a neophyte and only using emacs b/c of org-mode). Thanks

I am using spacemacs 0.200.13 based on emacs 25.3.1 on a Macbook w/ macOS 10.13.4

Comment: Have you tried `M-x pixel-scroll-mode RET` already? "...offers a global minor mode which makes mouse-wheel scroll a line smoothly." (from documentation)

Comment: How would I install it in spacemacs where it is not included? Sorry for the basic question.

Comment: `pixel-scroll-mode` is new in Emacs 26.

Comment: Ah, that's why. Switched to v26 (using self-contained package from https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/releases for now) and switched to spacemacs develop branch. Scrolling is very smooth now, even without pixel-scroll-mode. I am still investigating what caused the previous jerkiness but thanks to you both, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs scrolling is traditionally line-by-line. However, as of Emacs 26.1, `pixel-scroll-mode` gives smoother scrolling.

Comment: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11549
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8rml8f/emacs_26_pixelscrollmode_gcs_like_theres_no/ ...